# Prestashop - How to modify a block

Tags: css, prestashop-1.6

I'd like to modify my "categories" block on my left navigation column.
It looks like this actually :

[image: default look]
This is how I'd like to render it by default :

[image: expected look]

I need this modifications :

1. change the class of the cross's span (grower CLOSE -> grower OPEN)
2. change the display property of the list (none->block)

The problem is that I didn't found where to operate these modifications. Nor in the templates files nor in the back-office.

Could you please tell me where I need to re-write the code ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I found !

I had to modify css and js files.
To change the default values, i had to modifiy lines 81 & 84 of theme/css/modules/blockcategories/blockcategories.css. I swapped the default OPEN/CLOSE values.
The JS part is in theme/js/tools/treeManagment.js lines 62 & 71